# Generating checked-marked checkboxes based off an array

Tags: php, forms

I have an array of 6 US States (Hawaii, Ohio, Louisiana, Virginia, Tennessee, and Texas). I have another array of 3 US States that are selected from the 6 US states above (Ohio, Virginia, Texas).

How can I have PHP generate a checkbox list of the 6 states in total but with the selected states checked-marked? My code is listed below and I cannot seem to get it to run:

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #locationsBox { 
        border: 2px solid #ccc; 
        width: 250px; 
        height: 100px; 
        overflow-y: scroll; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="locationsBox">
    <form name="location_checkboxes">
    <?
    $locations = array("Hawaii","Ohio","Louisiana","Virginia","Tennessee","Texas");
    $selected_locations = array("Ohio","Virginia","Texas");

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($locations); $i++) {
        if (false != $key = array_search($selected_locations[$i],$locations) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="'.$locations[$key].'" />' . $locations[$key] . '<br />';
        } else {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$locations[$i].'" />' . $locations[$i] . '<br />';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What does it do instead of run? Error? I note that your `<input>`s have no `name=` attribute so they won't appear in `$_POST`.

Comment: Also I see an unclosed `)` on `if (false !=....)`

Comment: And the `checked` property's value should be `checked='checked'` not `checked='yes'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$locations = array("Hawaii","Ohio","Louisiana","Virginia","Tennessee","Texas");
$selected_locations = array("Ohio","Virginia","Texas");
foreach($locations as $l)
{
    if(in_array($l,$selected_locations))
    {
       echo '<input type="checkbox" name="location[]"     checked="checked" value="'.$l.'" />' . $l . '<br />';
        echo "<br />";
    }
     else 
    {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="'.$l.'" />' . $l . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this approach is very nice.

Comment: You're welcome! also you can change the name to "location[]" if you want those to be posted to your php as an array of values